# Amazon EMR streaming mapper / reducer not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, emr

i tryed to build my first EMR streaming application written in PHP.

on my local system this works well:
./producer/target/release/producer 1000 | php mapper.php | sort | php reducer.php

i also tryed to make the mapper / reducer executable and add a Shebang.

i used the "picker" to select the s3 path to the mapper / reducer but EMR complains in it's logs:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/..././mapper.php": error=2, No such file or directory

Seems that EMR did not copy the mapper file to the hadoop cluster.

any idea why the mapper is not found?

Answer (score 0):

The error is confusing; it's not mapper.php that's missing, but the php executable itself. PHP isn't installed on the latest EMR AMI core & task nodes. You'll need to install it.

Any easy solution is to add a bootstrap item. Create bootstrap.sh with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

yum -y install php
```

Then upload that to s3. Then, when you choose your bootstrap file, select bootstrap.sh from s3 and it will install PHP before it runs your steps.